# How to memorize user's progress through the application?

Tags: php, javascript, session, architecture

I'm facing an architecture problem I didn't manage to solve. I'm developing a little game in PHP and Javascript, and I need to save the user's progress. Now, the problem is that PHP can't determine when the user wins the level: it's done in Javascript. Is there any way to save the user's progress when he wins a level?

For example, when the user wins level 1, he gains access to level 2. If he tries to access level 2 without having completed the previous level, he gets redirected to the last completed one. In my controller I was doing the following:

```
if (1 !== $id) {
    if ($app['session']->get('last_level') !== ($id - 1)) {
        // redirect the user
    }
}
```

Now I need a way to store the **last_level** value into the session, an  operation that can't be simulated by the user.

Any hints?

Comment: Can't an AJAX request be simulated by the user?

Comment: You can't do a browser game with the little knowledge you have. Sorry.  I suggest you to start with something simpler then go with this

Comment: Yes, it can be simulated. However, the problem is that all the logic regarding whether a level is passed or not resides in the client. You can _never_ trust the client since you can run arbitrary JavaScript by firing up a console. So you should have some kind of verification on your backend anyway to ensure that the level has really been completed...

Comment: I'm absolutely not building a browser game. I'm just curious: I'm developing this software because I wanted to find a way to solve problems like this. Don't worry. I know what "understand your limits" means. :)

Comment: Good attitude! - taking on something beyond your limits (within reason) is one of the better ways of extending your limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to do the different `last_level` calculations on the server.  That way the user can't hack around with the JavaScript, and submit something on a specially crafted form.  So depending on what your storage system is (KV store, Database, Textfile, etc.), put that value in there, and retrieve it.

Ajax can help you out, but isn't necessary.  It depends on how your game is set up.  But if they complete the level, the server needs to be notified.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I want to do: put the last_level value in the session. The problem is there's no way for the server to determine the last completed level. The only way is through an AJAX request, but I was quite sure it could be simulated somehow.

Comment: Ajax isn't the only way to do it.  You do have other options.  Though Ajax is a /nice/ way of doing it.  It's difficult to give instructions on how to do this when we don't have an example of the game.  But what you can do is have the JavaScript set flags when a portion of the level has been completed.  This way, you can use them to calculate a value.  Run that value against the user's ID / session / when the page was loaded, and use that value to go through a function to calculate what level they're on.  Then to get the next level, use the value from the previously calculated level.

Comment: Well, that's just a very simple example application, so I don't think it's possible: there's a timer, and the user has to stop the timer between, e.g., 5 and 6 seconds. There's nothing to calculate here... am I wrong?

Comment: Well, how does the user stop the timer?  Do they click a button?  Do they press a key?  Do they have to click inside of a moving box?  Those are relative questions.  Because you can read mouse positions.  You can set a timer on the page when it loads.  Then you can use that to run against when the level started.  And use that to help compute the values.  There are lots of different things you can do.  But anything that you put in JavaScript can be manipulated.  That's Security 101.  So, you can try set up a more complicated checking system, to make it more difficult to spoof.

Comment: They click a button. As I already said, the mistake was to use Javascript. Instead, I will use PHP to save the start and end time into the session and to calculate whether the user won. Javascript will be used only to display a simple timer.

Comment: That's fine, but what I'm saying (and have been saying) is that you can use them in tandem.  You can use JavaScript to compliment the PHP.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

**If a user completes a level and then stays on the same page doing additional work:**

Then you'll probably want Ajax to send the new level info to the server as soon as the new level has been achieved. Thus:

1. Use cookies to store your php session id
2. From your Javascript client, use Ajax to invoke a php url on your server whenever the user wins a new level. Send the new level as a parameter. Can use POST or GET, doesn't matter.
3. The php program will receive the session id in the cookie, and the new level as a parameter. The php program will look up the user id from the session id, then store the new level the database.
4. Next time the main url of the php program is invoked, it will be able to look up the user's level.

**If the user presses "Next" button to go onward to the next level:**
Use Javascript, not Ajax, to change the POST parameters of the "Next" button.

You'd use POST, not GET, since seeing a url of foo.com/game?level=5 is a bit too obvious for people to cheat your game. POST will not show the level parameter in the url. More security: add a checksum parameter.

If any of the above is not clear, ask in comments or as a follow-up question.

Comment: Hmm... okay, that's much or less one of the solutions I came up with. What do you exactly min by "add a checksum parameter"?

Comment: Send a second parameter which is a checksum (such as CRC32) of the level. Or better: checksum the level plus a constant value, (to make the input string longer). Then calculate checksum again on server. If checksum sent as a param != calculated checksum then something is wrong. This is NOT real security but will slow down a casual user from cheating. If you want to ensure no cheating then you need to calculate (or verify) the level on the server. [CRC32 in Javascript](http://noteslog.com/post/crc32-for-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to take javascript's word for it that the level has been completed then just set a cookie from javascript.

> an operation that can't be simulated by the user

Sorry - but if it's javascript which dtermines when they've completed the level then there's nothing to stop the user falsifying the results.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think the mistake was to use Javascript. I think I'll use PHP to perform the real calculations, and Javascript just to display the timer.