# Accuracy of Javascript timers

Tags: php, javascript, timer

Note that this is a follow-up question from my previous one: "[How to memorize user's progress through the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020044/how-to-memorize-users-progress-through-the-application/)".

After the answers, I understood that the mistake was to use Javascript to determine whether the user won the game. So I moved the logic into my controller: I save the UNIX timestamp into the session when the user starts the level, and calculate the difference when the user ends it. If it took no more than X seconds for the user to complete the level, I allow him/her to access the next one, and so on and so forth.

Everything worked fine, until I decided to introduce a client-side timer made in Javascript. The timer isn't obviously accurate as the PHP one, since it relies on the user's CPU and not on the server's one. So, the two timers are not synchronized. The game still works when the time frame is large (e.g. the user has to complete the level between 4 and 10 seconds), but it doesn't work as expected when the time frame is smaller (1 or 2 seconds). Even if the user clicks during the winning time frame, PHP will tell him he didn't win.

I've made some tries and here are my results:

```
|===========================|
| # |  PHP  |   JS  | Ratio |
|===========================|
| 1 |  6.20 |  5.29 |  1.17 |
| 2 |  7.32 |  6.27 |  1.16 |
| 3 |  2.89 |  2.24 |  1.29 |
| 4 | 22.56 | 20.13 |  1.12 |
| 5 | 50.15 | 45.24 |  1.10 |
|===========================|
```

(Yes, I know, this is the worst ASCII table ever made.)

And this is the timer I've made using jQuery (I'm not really trained with this language, so it's probably also the worse Javascript timer ever made):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window['time'] = {
        'cseconds': 0,
        'dseconds': 0,
        'seconds': 0,
        'minutes': 0,
        'hours': 0
    };

    $("#timer").everyTime(10, function() {
        window['time']['cseconds'] += 1;

        if (window['time']['cseconds'] > 9) {
            window['time']['cseconds'] = 0;
            window['time']['dseconds'] += 1;
        }

        if (window['time']['dseconds'] > 9) {
            window['time']['dseconds'] =  0;
            window['time']['seconds']  += 1;
        }

        if (window['time']['seconds'] > 60) {
            window['time']['seconds'] =  0;
            window['time']['minutes'] += 1;
        }

        if (window['time']['minutes'] > 60) {
            window['time']['minutes'] =  0;
            window['time']['hours']   += 1;
        }

        cseconds = window['time']['cseconds'].toString();
        dseconds = window['time']['dseconds'].toString();
        seconds  = window['time']['seconds'].toString();
        minutes  = window['time']['minutes'].toString();
        hours    = window['time']['hours'].toString();

        if (seconds.length < 2) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        if (minutes.length < 2) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (hours.length < 2) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }

        $("#timer").text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + dseconds + cseconds);
    });
});
```

I've tried different solutions, like AJAX: first the timer relied only on AJAX requests (which led to thousand of HTTP request), and it was still imprecise. Then I modified it to synchronize with PHP every X seconds, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why AJAX solution didn't work? It was the second solution in my mind. It has to work, because the time comes from server...

The first solution is quite simple and I think the most accurate. Instead of relying on a Javascript periodical execution of function, try to rely on system date time. Use a Javascript periodical function to update the time on screen, but get that time using system date/time instead of a simple `seconds += 1`! Some pseudo code:

```
var startTime = new Date();

// Every 1/2 second or less...
var elapsedTimeInMs = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();
```

However I suggest you to read the documentation for `Date` objects.

Comment: It seems to work well. It's so obvious now that you showed me. :D Let me do some tests and I'll probably accept your answer.

Comment: Hi, @lorenzo-s can you elaborate with some code?
I'm also in a similar situation

Answer (score 3):

If you time an event by doing `new Date()` at both the start and end of the event and compare the elapsed time difference between those, you will get very accurate timing using javascript.  The precision of timers in modern browsers is often a few milliseconds and in older browsers no worse than 15ms.

Your code looks like it's trying to use an interval timer and counting intervals.  That will not be very accurate.  Because javascript is single threaded, the exact timing of when a javascript timer fires is not very precise so it should not be relied upon for accurate timing of an event.  In otherwords, it's much more accurate to measure the elapsed system time rather than counting timer intervals that have fired.

Comment: Exactly, stop relying on timeouts to increase your timer locally, know the initial timer, the local time when you got that reading from the server (through ajax) and then all you need is the current local time. It's as simple as `initialserver+currentlocal-initiallocal`.

Comment: I believe a few modern browsers will drop timer resolution on unfocused windows/tabs to reduce processor load when those tabs are inactive, so that would make interval precision even worse if a user tabs away from the web app

Comment: You're right: this is another problem I solved using the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use AJAX, but only on the event of the user finishing the game, to obtain the Time on the server...

Comment: Yup, but I think his problem is that displayed time (that has to be calculated using JS) is not in sync with server one, fetched via AJAX when game ends...

Comment: I can't: I need the user to know the server's time in every moment. Plus, it's PHP that determines when the user finished the game, so it wouldn't make any sense to display the time after the level has been completed.

Comment: sorry, i haven't thought of that